# JSON fields are showing that shouldn't be based on the view

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have fields showing in my JSON that shouldn't be showing based on the view I'm trying to use.  I believe I'm encoding use hte view correctly...

`ObjectMapperProvider`

```
@Component
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews#Handling_of_.22view-less.22_properties
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, Boolean.FALSE);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Code to generate JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Views.ShutdownView.class);

//persist the queue to the database
if (getQueue().size() > 0) {
    try {
        getEntity().setQueue(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(getQueue()));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        logger.severe("Unable to JSONify: "+getEntity());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Part of the JSON I'm seeing includes:

```
                 "uuid":"c0fbb88f-893e-4375-91a0-1ebb315e7ad7",
                 "inProduction":false,
                 "updated":null,
                 "created":1372346197000,
```

When the only field that should be showing is the `uuid`:

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 128, precision = 0)
@Basic
@JsonView({Views.ShutdownView.class})
public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

private Boolean inProduction;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "in_production", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 0, precision = 0)
@Basic
public Boolean getInProduction() {
    return inProduction;
}

public void setInProduction(Boolean inProduction) {
    this.inProduction = inProduction;
}

private Timestamp updated;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "updated", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public Timestamp getUpdated() {
    return updated;
}

public void setUpdated(Timestamp updated) {
    this.updated = updated;
}

private Timestamp created;

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "created", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
    this.created = created;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that need to be fixed before this will work

- You posted the code for your `ObjectMapperProvider` but in the code sample you do `new ObjectMapper()` so it won't have your `DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` setting
- `withView` methods return a new instance, they don't modify the instance that they're called on. Also, you probably don't want to modify the serialization config in this case. The correct code would be: `mapper.writerWithView(Views.ShutdownView.class).writeValueAsBytes(getQueue())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the field visibility on the `ObjectMapper` like so:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.None)
```

Comment: I used `mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);` and that didn't change the output